# Windows 7 CD-ROM shortcut

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

can someone explain how I can have a .lnk file on a cd-rom that can have parameters to locate the cd-rom path no matter what drive letter it happens to be in?  In other words, no matter if it's D:folder\file or E:\folder\file...as a .lnk file has an absolute path...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Link files actually do support relative paths.  See [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418541/how-do-i-create-a-shortcut-lnk-with-a-relative-target) for more details.  There are also some tricks you can use, like creating a link to cmd.exe, which will always run, and then launching your executable from the present directory.